# Magento 1: clarification regarding translation methods

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, localisation, certification

I'm currently studying for the MFC and I've [downloaded the guide from Demac Media.](https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-frontend-developer-certification-exam-study-guide-qa/)

One of the question to ask yourself (from the official Magento study guide) is **which methods are available for translation ?**

And [according to the Demac Media guide](https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-frontend-developer-certification-exam-study-guide-qa/#Internationalization) it is the following:

- Inline translation
- Locale translation files (translation.csv)
- `core_translate` package
- JavaScript translate.js

But to me this list does not make sense because I don't know **what is the difference between inline translation and `core_translate` package ?**

AFAIK, when you use the inline translation system in Magento 1, the translations are stored in the `core_translate` table.

Comment: I think `core_translate` package stand for theme translate , if we change theme it will change the translate on the other side db translate bases on the store

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I don't think so. Theme translates are CSV files so it is number 2 in the list: **Locale translation files**

Comment: You're missing the `app/locale/[iso]/[Company_Module].csv` files.

Comment: Then It would be module translation because that's the only thing left

Comment: @JulienLachal both theme and `app/locale` translations are in point number two: **Locale translation files**

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala see my last comment

Comment: Are you sure they're processed the same way though?

Comment: @JulienLachal well pretty much via the fallback system. To me the wording does not make much sense in this list

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that they might have made a mistake in their post?

Comment: @JulienLachal totally but I didn't say it in my question as I always assume I may be wrong in the first place. To me it's a mistake but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Tbh I think you're not. Or if you are, we're all missing something ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging around, to me this is clearly a mistake. Here are the several types of translations available:

- **Inline translation** : can be enabled via the backend. The translations are stored in the `core_translate` database table.
- **JavaScript translation**: can be done via code such as `Translator.add('Text to Translate', <?php echo $this->__('Text to Translate'));`
- **Global translation** : can be done via CSV files stored under the `app/locale` folder.
- **Theme translation** : can be dona via CSV files similar to the global method but stored in `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/locale/<lg_LG>/translate.csv`

Answer (score 0):

This Article explain very well: https://belvg.com/blog/magento-certified-developer-exam-internationalization.html

1. Module translation

Module translations are stored in app/locale/languagecode_COUNTRYCODE/ folder in form of csv files, named as Namespace_Modulename.csv All string in extensions that are inside __() method can be translated this way

2. Theme translation

Strings can be translated inside your theme, for that you just need to set locale via Magento admin area, then create translate.csv in app/design/frontend///locale/ languagecode_COUNTRYCODE and put your translated strings inside this CSV

“My Cart”,”My Basket”

“My Account”,”Account”

There are a lot of tips&tricks that can be described on this subject (module and theme translations), so I feel like they deserve an individual article. Stay tuned!

3. Inline translation

To enable inline translation you need to log into Admin panel and go to System -> Configuration -> Developer.

You need to select Store view from scope select and enable inline translation for this desired store view there.